# Does the branch I'm on using 'git log' matter if I use the same commit hashes?

Tags: git, git-checkout, git-log

Behold! I have the following Git structure:

```
A-...-C-D-E      (develop branch)
         \
          X-Y    (feature1 branch)
```

Where A, B, C, D, and E are commits on the develop branch, and X and Y are commits on a branch named feature1. Commits A and C are seperated by an unknown amount of commits.
Let's also say that commit A has (partial) commit hash `b0a710ad5` and commit Y has (partial) commit hash `0fc0d3`.

Now, there are two scenarios of interest. One where I checkout develop and run

```
git log --oneline b0a710ad5..0fc0d3
```

And the second scenario, where I instead checkout feature1, and do the same command:

```
git log --oneline b0a710ad5..0fc0d3
```

If I had to guess what these scenarios returned, I would say that the first would give me an error, since commit Y does not exist on the develop branch. And I would guess that the second scenario would give me a legitimate Git log. However, I was quite mistaken. It didn't seem to matter what branch I was on: both commands gave me the exact same logs. It appears that `git log` can see commits from other branches, *which thing I never had supposed*.

Can `git log` find a commit on any branch in the local repository? Does it search and find commits remotely if it can't find it on any local branches? Does it truly not matter what branch I am on when I run a `git log ..` with commit hashes? Oh, the possibilities.

Comment: Hashes are valid wherever you are. In fact they are valid even in bare mode (where you don't even have a working directory). Your git repository must know them though, it won't decide to go on the internet by itself.

Comment: The "./.git" local directory contains your local git object database, which contains the most recent copy of all known objects based on the last time you typed "git pull" or "git fetch" against whatever remotes you have setup.  Git `log` command has access to that local "./.git/" database. (p.s.  always type "[git pull -r](https://mergebase.com/doing-git-wrong/2018/03/07/fun-with-git-pull-rebase/)" and never type "git pull") ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [spectras noted in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50109381/does-the-branch-im-on-using-git-log-matter-if-i-use-the-same-commit-hashes#comment87236131_50109381), the hashes are valid everywhere.

For the most part, Git just uses a name to *find* a hash.  That is, a branch name like `develop` or `feature1` is just a human-readable—and, importantly, *changeable*—name for some particular hash ID.  That hash ID is mostly what Git cares about.  A command like `git log` will translate from name to hash ID, then start working with the commit.  The commit itself contains another hash ID, for its parent commit, and `git log` will look at *that* commit, which has yet another hash ID, and so on.

We can link up each of these commits, in a backwards-pointing fashion, using the branch name to find the *last* commit, like this:

```
... <-grandparent <-parent <-0fc0d3   <--branchname
```

and that's essentially what Git does.

When using a range operation like `b0a710ad5..0fc0d3`, Git goes straight for the hash ID: `0fc0d3` is a *positive reference* so Git finds that commit.  Because of the two dots `..` between them, the first hash ID, `b0a710ad5`, is syntactically equivalent to `^b0a710ad5`: it's a *negative reference*.  Git also finds that commit, but it uses that to *suppress* showing some commit(s).  If `b0a710ad5` itself is right in the chain, Git *stops* when reaching `b0a710ad5`.  If `b0a710ad5` *isn't* in the chain—for instance, if the commit chains look something more like this:

```
    b0a710ad5  ...   <--somename
        /
great-...-grandparent <-... <-parent <-0fc0d3   <--branchname
```

then `b0a710ad5` suppresses the *great-<sup>n</sup>th-grandparent*, which Git finds by walking backwards from `b0a710ad5`.

This process of walking backwards, starting from a later commit, is how Git determines the *reachability* of a commit.  An earlier commit is *reachable* from some later commit—or from some name—if we start at the later commit and work backwards and reach the earlier commit.

#### Names sometimes *do* matter

Note that when you make a *new* commit, you generally do it while being "on" some branch.  Being *on a branch* means that Git attaches the name `HEAD` to that branch, so that if we draw our commits with the branch names at the right, pointing to the *tip* (most recent) commits, one of those names has `HEAD` attached:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- develop
         \
          I--J   <-- feature1 (HEAD)
```

(The single uppercase letters here stand in for the actual hash IDs, which are too unwieldy to bother with.)

If we make a new commit now, Git sets the new commit to the hash ID of the current commit `J` and then *writes that new commit's hash ID* into the name `feature1`.  The fact that `HEAD` is attached to `feature1`, and `feature1` currently names commit `J`, is how this all works.  Git makes the new commit `K`:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- develop
         \
          I--J   <-- feature1 (HEAD)
              \
               K   [make new commit: parent is HEAD]
```

then *writes `K` into `feature1`* to get:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- develop
         \
          I--J
              \
               K   <-- feature1 (HEAD)
```

which we can redraw on fewer lines:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- develop
         \
          I--J--K   <-- feature1 (HEAD)
```

Note that `HEAD` remains attached to `feature1` throughout the operation; it's `feature1` itself that changes, to store a new hash ID.

(When you use `git push`, you also use these names, to identify commits you want to send to some other Git repository.  You ask them to set *their* names based on *your* names.  When you use `git fetch`, some *other* Git repository has names that point to commits that have hash IDs, and your Git copies the *commits*—which keep the same hash ID—but then writes new `origin/*` names into *your* repository, so as to remember *their* names without colliding with your branch names.  So the names matter here too—but the hash IDs matter at least as much, as they are the "true names" of the actual commits.)